# Export every MySQL table row into different .csv files

Tags: php, mysql, csv

In `php` file values are selected from MySQL table and print out with `while` loop

```
<?php
$result = $conn->query('SELECT Column_1,Column_2,Column_3  FROM `dbtest`');

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
Header 
<?php
print_r($row["Column_1"]);
print_r($row["Column_2"]);  
print_r($row["Column_3"]); 
?>
Footer 
<?php  } ?>
```

Now I am trying to generate separate `.csv` file per every iteration. Code below works, but print everything into one file. I have tried to put it into `while` loop, but it haven't solved the problem, only first iteration is added into `.csv` file.

```
<?php
 $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp);
    }
    die;
}
?>
```

May someone know where I am missing the point? I am only starting and missing some theory. Many thanks for all possible help.

**UPDATE** file creation inside loop

```
    <?php
    $result = $conn->query('SELECT Column_1,Column_2,Column_3  FROM `dbtest`');    
    $x = 1;                  
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
    Header 
    <?php
    print_r($row["Column_1"]);
    print_r($row["Column_2"]);  
    print_r($row["Column_3"]); 
    ?>
    Footer 
    <?php 

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    if ($fp && $result) {
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export'.$x.'.ldt');
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            fputcsv($fp);
        }
        die;
    }        
    $x++;
    } 
?>
```

Comment: maybe you need to change filename in each iteration

Comment: u are opening one file `$fp` and put the content in `same file`

Comment: put the whole file creation code in a loop and change file name in each iteration

Comment: @Anandhunadesh I have put it into `while` loop, but it only creates one file with first iteration inside. Or you mean that I have to create separate loop only for file creation?

Comment: please post the code you tried

Comment: @Anandhunadesh I have updated my question

Comment: replace `fputcsv($fp, $row);` this with `fputcsv(rand().'.csv', $row);`

Comment: @arunkumar same problem, only 1 file is generated with warning inside   `fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in`